# Don't know why I'm receiving this error "SyntaxError: invalid token"?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am learning python from scratch but while learning i received an error while initializing a value of 01000 to a variable. Well, I don't know why I'm receiving this kind of error.

```py
>>> a = 01000
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    a = 01000
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid token
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the 0 at the start. Try this:

```
a = 1000
```

It doesn`t matter because

> 01000 = 1000

Except if you mean it in binary. Then I advise to use strings:

```
a = "01000"
```